# Elegant way to prevent StackOverflow in Recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to port [this Genetic Algorithm](https://www.burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-genetic-algorithms-part-1-javascript/),
and I made a recursive function for advancing from one generation to another.

However, as I'm new to recursion in C# (and in general), I evidently bumped into StackOverflowException when there were too many generations (more than around 4500).

In order to solve the problem, I made Generation() return a bool, so when the genetic algorithm reachs max fitness (goal), it returns true. Else it returns Generation().

If it's about to overflow (Generation > 4500), it returns false.

Now In Main(), to keep Generation() running until it returns true, I use a while loop, so it will start over the recursion until it completes.

This is way more efficient than doing Task.Run, so I went for this approach.

Is this good practice? Are there any more elegant ways of preventing StackOverflows without sacrificing performance?

**Population.cs:**

```
class Population
{

    public int GenerationNumber { get; private set; }
    public int TotalGenerationNumber { get; private set; }
    public const int StackGenerationLimit = 4500;

    public Population()
    {

        GenerationNumber = 0;
        TotalGenerationNumber = 0;


    }
    public bool Generation()
    {
        // Work
        // if(HasReachedGoal) return true;

        GenerationNumber++;


        if(GenerationNumber > StackGenerationLimit)
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return Generation();
        }


    }

    public void ResetStack()
    {
        TotalGenerationNumber += GenerationNumber; // I store the total number of generation for information purposes
        GenerationNumber = 0; // Reset the recursion depth value
    }




}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Population population = new Population();

        while (!population.Generation()) // Until it reaches its goal
        {
            population.ResetStack();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End. Generations: " + population.TotalGenerationNumber);


    }
}
```

Comment: Usually you dont have to keep a recursive method running

Comment: If you get to the point where you get a stackoverflow, you should probably consider altering the approach to a non-recursive one. In this case it's actually pretty simple, since the algorithm is basically "mate generation, mutate generation, filter generation, repeat". Sounds more like a loop to me than a recursion. And in fact this is even better in terms of performance than recursion (if implemented properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid stack overflow is to not use recursion. You're already half way to the answer with your workaround. Now you just need to ask yourself the question of what you gain from recursion any more? If your `return Generation();` statement in the `Generation` function were instead changed to `return false;` then you would go back to the main loop where it would call `Generation()` again.

Of course having made this change there are now a lot of other tidy ups you can do. You no longer need your stack reset, you no longer need the if statement that checks for the generation limit and all your repetitions are done from the while loop.

So your two methods:

```
public bool Generation()
{
    TotalGenerationNumber++;
    // Work
    return HasReachedGoal;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Population population = new Population();
    bool hasCompleted = false;
    while (!hasCompleted) // Until it reaches its goal
    {
        hasCompleted = population.Generation();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("End. Generations: " + population.TotalGenerationNumber);
}
```

Note that in the tidyup I've introduced a bool variable called `hasCompleted` since I find it more readable to use a variable for the while condition and prefer to have the work inside the loop itself.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you would be better off preping the while loop and sending in the data you want to check into the .Generation call.  then if it returns false, you update the data. Something like this:

```
    Population population = new Population();
    var input = new InputDto() { ... };
    while (!population.Generation(input)) // Until it reaches its goal
    {
        // update input
    }
```

This prevents a too deeply nested call that gets the error you are describing.