# StackOverflowException when trying to make label scroll

Tags: c#

When making a label scroll, when the information is to large, I get a StackOverflow Exception.

Code in question:

If anyone knows of a fix, please answer below.

```
private async Task LblScroll(int time)
{
    lblScroll.Location = new Point(lblScroll.Location.X - 5, lblScroll.Location.Y);
    if (lblScroll.Location.X < (-lblScroll.Width))
    {
        if (stopScroll)
            return;
        else
            lblScroll.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width + lblScroll.Text.Length, lblScroll.Location.Y);
    }

    if (!stopScroll)
    {
        await Task.Delay(time);
        await LblScroll(time);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Whats the rest of the code. Is this an event? is this the method name `LblScroll` ?

Comment: If i had to take a guess, you are recursively calling `LblScroll` this is likely the wrong approach. use a timer or a loop

Comment: @MichaelRandall: the declaration was on the same line as the backticks so they weren't rendered. Your suspicion is right on.

Comment: @madreflection ahh ok, that makes more sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackOverFlow in recursive function C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025074/stackoverflow-in-recursive-function-c-sharp). See also: [Elegant way to prevent StackOverflow in Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43591369/8967612).

Comment: [How to make label reappear as soon as it's going out of panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297397/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

I had to switch from using awaits to timers. This worked like a charm.